# Question on Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $ T:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is a linear transformation such that the kernel of T is  {$(x,-x): x\in\mathbb R $}. If T takes (1,0) to 1 then T takes (1,1) to which number?

I tried like this that  $(a,b) =(a-b)(1,0)+b(1,1)$.

I struck here.

where can I use the kernel information to get the map?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $(1,-1)$ is in the kernel so $T(1,-1)=0$. But on the other hand, using linearity $$T(1,-1)=T(1,0)-T(0,1)=1-T(0,1) =0$$ This shows that $T(0,1)=1$. Now using linearity again we have $$T(1,1)=T(1,0)+T(0,1)=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 2):

$(1,1)=(2,0)+(-1,1)$ $\to$  $T(1,1)=T(2,0)+T(-1,1)=2T(1,0)+T(-1,1)=2+0=2$

Answer (score 1):

I think here T is a linear transformation on (a,b) which takes it to a+b. this sis beacause ker T:= T(a,b)=0 ; so we get one possiblity as T(a,b) = a + b.This can be verified by the fact that T(1,0)=1;

thus T(1,1)=2:

correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks